# Can DBIx::Class use the SQL window functions lag and lead?

Tags: perl, dbix-class

I need to find the previous and next record according to a previous database search, starting at a specific row. In SQL, window functions `lead` and `lag` are very useful, but apparently there is no support in DBIx::Class for these.

I am planning a mixture between DBIx::Class and plain SQL, but not sure if there is a better solution.

Comment: Can you show a minimal runnable example that shows how you will use these functions?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, something similar to this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-lead-and-lag-function/